# Copy and sort macro in vba

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I am designing a macro that will copy and sort data by a key in vba.  I have begun to write the code and it has worked well so far but for some reason I get an Object Required error at the line : `Set rng1 = SourceData.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)`.  I am unsure why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng1Row As Range
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Sheet1.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "SourceData"
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Set rng1 = SourceData.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow
rng1Row.Sort Key1:=Range("A1")



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because `SourceData` is not a thing. It looks like that is supposed to be a worksheet or a range or something, but you have not declared it, nor have you set it.

Update: `SourceData` is a sheet. To refer to a sheet by name you should use `Sheets("Sheetname")`. Furthermore, there is no need to refer to the `cells` of the sheet to get a specific range in the sheet, just go right to the range: `Sheets("SourceData").Range("A2:A" & N)`

Comment: Didn't it become a thing when I Added it as a sheet?

Comment: That was my assumption is that it was a sheet. SourceData is merely the name of the sheet. The actually sheet will be "Sheet4" or something. "Sheet4" will have a name of "SourceData". In otherwords: `ThisWorkbook.Sheet4.Name` is "SourceData". Use the reference I added to the answer above to properly refer to a sheet by name.

Comment: Ok. That worked. but now it is saying the subscript is out of range.

Comment: Probably it's your value for "N". Hit "Debug" when it gets that error and look at your "locals" window to see what the value is for "N". My guess is it's probably "1", making your Range("A2:A1") nonsensical.